# Prove equality of stopped sigma algebras under right continuity

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, filtrations

Given the definitions:

$\mathcal{F}_\tau := \{A ∈ \mathcal{F} : A ∩ \{τ ≤ t\} ∈ \mathcal{F}_t \quad ∀t ≥ 0 \}$

$\mathcal{F}_{\tau+} := \{A ∈ \mathcal{F} : A ∩ \{τ < t\} ∈ \mathcal{F}_t\}$

How do we rigorously prove that $\mathcal{F}_\tau ⊂ \mathcal{F}_{\tau+}$ and $\mathcal{F}_\tau = \mathcal{F}_{\tau+}$ if $(\mathcal{F}_t)$ is right-continuous?

I can do the first part of this question, the inclusion, but I am stuck trying to show equality when the filtration is right-continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the secnnd part let $E \in \mathcal F_{\tau+}$. Then $E\cap \{\tau <t\} \in \mathcal F_t$ for all $t$. Hence $E\cap \{\tau <t+\frac  1 n\} \in \mathcal F_{t+\frac  1n}$. So $\bigcap_{ n\geq m} E\cap \{\tau <t+\frac  1 n\} \in \mathcal F_{t+\frac  1m}$.  But this says $E \cap \{\tau \leq t\} \in \mathcal F_{t+\frac  1m}$. Since this is true for all $m$ we see that $E\cap\{ \tau \leq t\} \in \mathcal F_{t+}=\mathcal F_t$ by hypothesis.

Comment: Should this say: "But this says $E\cap\{\tau\leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}_{t+\frac{1}{m}}$" rather than "But this says $\{\tau\leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}_{t+\frac{1}{m}}$" ?

Comment: @JacobM Yes, of course.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for your help!